# Why isn't my palindrome working?

Tags: java

I'm an aspiring java user taking college courses and I've run into a problem. My prof. told us to write a java program that detects a 5 digit number based palindrome. I've written something but it won't work the way I've planned. Could I get some help please? Using netbeans IDE.

```
package palindrome;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String stringNumber;
        int number;
        String stringPal;
        int palindrome;

        stringNumber = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Please, if you will, enter a five digit palindrome: ");
        number = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);

        if (number < 10000 && number > 99999) {
            System.out
                    .println("Your number is invalid, please enter a FIVE digit number: ");
        } else if (number % 10 == number % 100) {
            System.out.println("your number: " + number + "is a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You FAIL loser");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you keep insulting yourself like *You FAIL loser* of course you don't want to find your own errors :).

Comment: By the way, 999 % 10 = 9 and 999 % 100 = 99. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: yeah. The answer needs some work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, that your logic for palindrome is wrong.

What you need to check is if the string/number is same when reversed.

So, suppose you want to check whether the a string is palindrome, reverse it and check if it is same as the original string.

You should try to complete this template:

```
boolean isPalindrome(String s){

   String reverseString = reverseString(s);

   if(reverseString.equals(s)){
        return true;
   }

   return false;
}

String reverse(String s){
  //add code to reverse String. (and optionally check if it is Integer, if it is a requirement)
}
```

You can now google how to reverse a string.

PS: You might wanna take a look at `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the help I was needing. It's right at my level and not too complex for where I'm at in Java right now. I greatly appreciate the help from sam-i-am and rgettman as well

Answer (score 11):

Your palindrome logic is incorrect.  You check if the remainder when divided by 10 equals the remainder when divided by 100 - that is the case if and only if there is a 0 in the tens digit.  That is not the definition of a [palindrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome).

Comment: +1 for not providing a palindrome implementation, instead leading to OP to find his/her own solution

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand, how number % 10 == number % 100, implies palindrome, but all it does is compare the value of the last 2 digits to the value of the last 1 digit.

My advice would be to take input as a `string` or `char` array and the compare the last element of the string to the first, and then continue until you hit the middle

here's some psudo-code:

```
isPalindrome = true;

for i=0 to stringLength

    if(input[i] != input[length - i - 1])
        isPalindrome = false;
```